# HttpClient and non-ASCII URL characters (á,é,í,ó,ú)

Tags: java, url, uri, httpclient, mediawiki-api

'Long time reader, first time poster' here.

I'm in the process of making a [bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots) for a spanish Wiki I administer. I wanted to make it from scratch, since one of the purposes of me making it is to practice Java. However, I ran into some trouble when trying to make GET requests with HttpClient to URIs that contain non-ASCII characters such as á,é,í,ó or ú.

```
String url = "http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Categoría:Mejoras de las Botas"
method = new GetMethod(url);
client.executeMethod(method);
```

When I do the above, GetMethod complains about the URI:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://es.pruebaloca.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Categoría:Mejoras%20de%20las%20Botas&cmlimit=500&format=xml': Invalid query
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:222)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.<init>(GetMethod.java:89)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.HttpRequest.request(HttpRequest.java:69)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.HttpRequest.request(HttpRequest.java:120)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.Action.getCategoryMembers(Action.java:38)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.<init>(BotComponent.java:58)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.main(BotComponent.java:80)
```

Note that in the URI shown in the stack trace, spaces are encoded into `%20` and the `í`s are left as is. That exact same URI works perfectly on a browser, but I can't get around into GetMethod accepting it.

I've also tried doing the following:

```
URI uri = new URI(url, false);
method = new GetMethod(uri.getEscapedURI());
client.executeMethod(method);
```

This way, `URI` escaped the `i`s, but double escaped the spaces (`%2520`)...

```
http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Categor%C3%ADa:Mejoras%2520de%2520las%2520Botas&cmlimit=500&format=xml
```

Now, if I don't use any spaces in the query, there's no double escaping and I get the desired output. So if there wasn't any possibility of non-ASCII characters, I wouldn't need to use the `URI` class and wouldn't get the double escaping. In an attempt to avoid the first escaping of the spaces, I tried this:

```
URI uri = new URI(url, true);
method = new GetMethod(uri.getEscapedURI());
client.executeMethod(method);
```

But the `URI` class didn't like it:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: Invalid query
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.parseUriReference(URI.java:2049)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.<init>(URI.java:167)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.HttpRequest.request(HttpRequest.java:66)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.HttpRequest.request(HttpRequest.java:121)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.Action.getCategoryMembers(Action.java:38)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.<init>(BotComponent.java:58)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.main(BotComponent.java:80)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.http.Action.getCategoryMembers(Action.java:39)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.<init>(BotComponent.java:58)
    at net.metroidover.categorybot.bot.BotComponent.main(BotComponent.java:80)
```

Any input on how to avoid this double escaping would be greatly appreciated. I've lurked all around with absolutely no luck.

Thanks!

**Edit:** The solution that works best for me is parsifal's one, but, as an addition, I'd like to say that setting the path with `method.setPath(url)` made `HttpMethod` reject a cookie I needed to save:

```
Aug 26, 2011 4:07:08 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase processCookieHeaders
WARNING: Cookie rejected: "wikicities_session=900beded4191ff880e09944c7c0aaf5a". Illegal path attribute "/". Path of origin: "http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php"
```

However, if I send the URI to the constructor and forget about the `setPath(url)`, the cookie gets saved without problem.

```
String url = "http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php";
NameValuePair[] query = { new NameValuePair("action", "query"), new NameValuePair("list", "categorymembers"),
            new NameValuePair("cmtitle", "Categoría:Mejoras de las Botas"), new NameValuePair("cmlimit", "500"),
            new NameValuePair("format", "xml") };
HttpMethod method = null;

...

method = new GetMethod(url);  // Or PostMethod(url)
method.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY); // It had been like this the whole time
method.setQueryString(query);
client.executeMethod(method);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [HttpMethodBase](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html), it appears that all `String` parameters have to be pre-encoded. The simplest solution is to constructor your URL in stages, with `setPath()` and the variant of `setQueryString()` that takes an array of name-value parameters.

Comment: Yay! That works perfectly. I was actually already sending the parameters as an `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`, so I didn't have to change much the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [`UrlEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to encode your queryString values (not the whole queryString).

```
UrlEncoder.encode("Categoría:Mejoras de las Botas", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: That works pretty well, but you'd have to encode all query parameters separately. I find parsifal's answer more useful since all `NameValuePair`s get encoded at once with `method.setQueryString(pairs);`, being `pairs` a `NameValuePair[]`.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try adding the params as `NameValuePair`, the problem here is that when you escape the URL everything in the URL is escaped including things like  http://.. thats why the system is complaining.

you can also escape just the arguments using `URLEncoder.encode()`, just pass the get params to this & append the return value to the URL.

`String url = "http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php?"+URLEncoder.encode("action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Categoría:Mejoras de las Botas");`

Comment: I think every parameter must be encoded separately, else the & and the = will be encoded.

Comment: Yep, like @JB Nizet says, you have to encode it separately or else you'll get `http://es.metroid.wikia.com/api.php?action%3Dquery%26list%3Dcategorymembers%26c‌​mtitle%3DCategor%C3%ADa%3AMejoras+de+las+Botas`.